# Why Oracle does not support "group by 1,2,3"?

Tags: oracle, group-by

It is really inconvenient that Oracle does not support the syntax "group by 1,2,3" like MySQL/PostgreSQL does, is anyone aware of why Oracle does not want to support this? This should not be difficult, right?

Comment: I really doubt that this "feature" is supported in PostgreSQL

Comment: At least it is now, 8 years later, and I think it was also 3 years ago. Still not in Oracle though.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, when you go by common sense,  column aliases can be used in a `ORDER BY` or a outer query only. Because, when you do a `ORDER by`, it happens only after the rows selection, by that time the alias is available. But during a `GROUP BY`, only after the grouping the selection is done, so until grouping is completed, oracle unaware of the column aliases.

i think, it is pretty much straight forward. may be other DBMS support them, implementing some SQL preprocessing.

So, in short, since the `SELECT` happens only after `GROUP BY`, and as column aliases are made only in `SELECT`, oracle dont support it! The programmer too, when understood this, may not have a need for wanting column aliases in grouping. Atleast me.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but technologies are evolving towards easier to use, not vice-versa, right? In some of my use cases, one of the column is a huge "case when" with more than thousand rows, without this feature, I have to repeat the thousand rows in group by clause, but if Oracle has this feature, that thousand rows could be replaced by a single digit, would it be better?

Comment: I get your pain point. But, imagining the case statement you mean and the grouping involved for large data sets, certainly will impact the performance. May be oracle's existing optimizer doesnt favour it. I wonder will any dbms works fast at it. Technology ing taking huge leaps, but does that mean, we should follow bad policies? Oracle is succesfull in its OLTP by being precise and consistent. And I have strong feeling, these kind of improvements may hinder them. It is just like apple hesitating to bring it fancy features compromising the performance!

Comment: My pain point is not performance, actually thousands of lines of "case when" is not performance bottleneck on Oracle, it is pretty fast. The pain point is readability, and redundancy.

Comment: thousands in not, but there are tables with billions of rows, and it will not be easy for database. What ever, as i said, your requirement is not impossible to oracle, just a add on, that oracle dont feel essential. ofcourse am not from Oracle :)